# Log Django shell operations to Google Cloud

Tags: python, django, logging, google-cloud-platform, ipython

We use Django shell (shell_plus to be specific) to do some operations with our data. We would like to log all the operations to comply with some regulations. For example, if we are in the shell now:

```
>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>> user.name
>> Steve
```

These 3 lines of code should be logged (ideally in our Google Cloud logging). What I've found so far, is using iPython and their logstart magic command. For this, I need to create a `ipython-config.py` file where I specify the log file:

```
# ipython-config.py
c = get_config()
time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ["%%logstart -t -o /var/log/django/shell-%s.log"" % time_stamp]
```

It now automatically will create a file and save everything (basically what we need). However, we need them to be in Google cloud logs.

One option we could use `google.cloud.logging` lib for python, create a client and then if we run logging.info(msg) (from standard python lib) we will have them logged to GC.

But iPython `logstart` magic function does not seem to even log to stdout, only to file.

Is there anything we can do to achieve this?

Comment: Is this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) useful for what you're looking for?

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez, not really. iPython seems to be using a different logger under the hood. May be we could redefine the impl of the ipython magic command, but would be an overkill for our needs, so looking for a more generic solution